# Is there a way to estimate the size of the search space for an arbitrary minizinc model?

Tags: python, optimization, constraint-programming, heuristics, minizinc

Given an arbitrary minizinc model (.mzn) file and an minizinc data (.dzn) file, I would like to estimate the size of the search space for the problem instance.

I wish to use an estimation of the size of the search space as a heuristic (general rule of thumb) for a scheduling algorithm.

Is there a way to do this automatically via a python script or the minizinc command line tool?

Comment: The quick answer would probably be "no". There are currently no such estimations for MiniZinc. However, in the general sense this is much more of a research question, and a lot of research has gone into the estimation of how hard constraint problems (or even more general combinatorial problems) are. I would suggest looking into the research angle, I'm sure this has been tried for scheduling problems.

Comment: Similar to @Dekker1 's answer, I agree that there is no general way to know this. The naive upper bound is the product of the domain sizes, which is not helpful and almost always not relevant. A related research area is solution counting, which tries to estimate the number of solutions. It is sometimes possible to make estimations based on exploring parts of the search space, but that would only work for an all-solution search and not for an optimizing search of first-solution search.

What is it that you want to achieve with this estimation?

Comment: @Dekker1 Thanks for your help :) Will look around and see if there are any related papers!

Comment: @Zayenz Thank you for your suggestion, I will look into Solution Counting. In response to your question, I am looking to create a cron type scheduler for scheduling and solving MiniZinc problems - similar to Google Cloud Scheduler. In the case where multiple problems are scheduled and to be solved at the same time, I would like some 'rule of thumb' to determine what problems to solve first. An estimation of the search space was the first metric that came to mind to determine this.

Comment: @jordanhasgul If the models to be solved are related but with varying data, it could in some cases be possible to create a simple ML estimator based on historical data. If the models are unrelated, I think you are probably out of luck and any estimation will be mostly useless (especially in the presence of first solution or optimizing search, solvers with automated free search, parallelism, restarts, randomization, ...)